# Angular bindins - property is visible in template but undefined in controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ecmascript-6

I want to Google Maps API in my Angular app. I am using ngMapAutocomplete (https://github.com/iazi/ngMapAutocomplete). I have problem with binding properties from ngMapAutocomplete to my controller. Here is my code.

Pug template:

```
 form(name='venueForm', ng-submit="vm.submit(venueForm)", novalidate)
  md-toolbar
    .md-toolbar-tools
      h2(translate="VENUE.TITLE")
      span(flex='')
      md-button.md-icon-button(ng-click='vm.cancel()')
        md-icon(md-svg-icon='mdi:close', aria-label='Close dialog')

  md-dialog-content(layout-padding)
    .md-dialog-content.venue-form-content
      span {{vm.nameDetails}}
      div(layout="row")
        md-input-container
          label(translate='VENUE.FORM.NAME')
          input(required, type='text', ng-model='vm.venue.name',
                ng-map-autocomplete, options="{}"
                details="vm.nameDetails", maps-input-change,
                placeholder="Zadejte název venue")

  md-dialog-actions(layout='row')
    span(flex='')
    md-button.md-raised(translate="BUTTONS.CANCEL", ng-click="vm.cancel()",
        aria-label='Cancel')
    md-button.md-raised.md-primary(type="submit", translate="BUTTONS.SAVE",
        ng-click="vm.save()", aria-label='Save venue')
```

JS code:

```
 function VenueFormController($scope) {
        this.$onInit = function () {
          this.nameDetails = {};
          this.cityDetails = {};
          this.addressDetails = {};
          this.cityOptions = {
            types: '(cities)',
          };
          this.addressOptions = {
            types: 'address',
          };
        };

        $scope.$on('GOOGLE_MAPS_AUTOCOMPLETE', function () {
          console.log(this);
          console.log(this.nameDetails);
        }.bind(this));

        this.cancel = function() {
          this.onCancel();
        };

        this.submit = function(form) {
          console.log(this.nameDetails);
          if (form.$invalid) {
            return;
          }

          this.onSave(this.selectedVenue);
        };

      }
```

```
  angular.module('gugCZ.webAdmin.venue.form', [
    'hc.marked',
    'ngMapAutocomplete',
    'gugCZ.webAdmin.events.form.orgs',
    'gugCZ.webAdmin.events.form.dates',
    'gugCZ.webAdmin.events.form.venue'
  ])
    .component('venueForm', {
      controller: VenueFormController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindings: {
        venue: '=',
        onCancel: '&',
        onSave: '&'
      },
      templateUrl: 'app/venue/form/form.html'

    })
    .directive('mapsInputChange', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element) {
          element.bind('change', () => {
            $scope.$emit('GOOGLE_MAPS_AUTOCOMPLETE', 
                {details: element.details, value: element.value});
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

I have to use custom directive which takes care about changes. Angular ng-change didn't work for some reason. In `$scope.$on` I have two console logs. First prints all properties of controller with `nameDetails` and its values. But the second ones prints `undefined`. And if I tried to put `nameDetails` to template, object with properties is shown. I added `console.log(this.nameDetails)` on button click and object with properties is shown. What am I doing wrong? I looked to ng-autocomplete-source code and I found this in bindings: `details: '=?'`. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: The custom `mapsInputChange` directive adds an event handler that conflicts with the event handler added by the [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). It would be wiser to use the [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive to react to changes

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Angular 1.x for a long time, but these are my thoughts:

```
input(required, type='text', ng-model='vm.venue.name', ng-map-autocomplete, options="{}"
            details="nameDetails", maps-input-change, placeholder="Zadejte název venue")
```

1) ng-model='vm.venue.name' is a venue.name property inside your controller

2) I'm not sure but details="nameDetails" should be nameDetails property in your scope, not in your controller

3) for detecting changes you can use $scope.$watch() inside your controller

HTH